# Swift AVAudioPlayer Restart from Beginning

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

I have an `AVAudioPlayer` stored in a property called "player". When the user clicks a button, it triggers this code:

```
@IBAction func restartPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    player.play()
}
```

The problem is happening when the user clicks the button twice in a row very quickly.

If the sound from the first click is still playing, it seems like the second call is ignored.

Instead, I'd like to either:

***a)*** restart the player from the beginning when the button is clicked a second time; or

***b)*** have two "instances" of the sound playing at the same time.

How would I go about achieving either or both of these options?

Comment: are you using the same button for play and reset?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Answering to *"either"* part (rather than *"both"*) of these options: **(a)** how to stop and play the sound from beginning:

```
@IBAction func restartPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    if player.playing {
        player.pause()
    }
    player.currentTime = 0
    player.play()
}
```

Regarding **(b)**: from the [Language Ref for `AVAudioPlayer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/AVAudioPlayer):

> Using an audio player you can:
>
> ...
>
> - Play multiple sounds simultaneously, **one sound per audio player**, with precise synchronization.

So you'd need two separate players to simultaneously (off-sync) play two separate sounds, even if both players use the same sound. I'd stick with **(a)**.

Comment: @MikeG Not according to the ref. docs (see link in answer): _"The stop method does not reset the value of the `currentTime` property to `0`. In other words, if you call stop during playback and then call play, playback resumes at the point where it left off."_

Comment: you @dfri are correct, `.stop()` does NOT reset the `currentTime` to 0, my apologies. `stop()` does *"Calling this method, or allowing a sound to finish playing, undoes the setup performed upon calling the play or prepareToPlay methods."* I thought this meant it must reset the resource to the beginning position but I guess not

Answer (score 0):

*dfri*'s answer updated for **Swift 4**

```
@IBAction func restartPressed(sender: UIButton) {

    if negativePlayer.isPlaying
    {
        negativePlayer.pause()
    }

    negativePlayer.currentTime = 0
    negativePlayer.play()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
player.seek(to: .zero)
player.play()
```